# AngularJs app cannot listen to localStorage changes from another window

Tags: javascript, angularjs, websocket, local-storage

In my AngularJS application two windows communicate through localStorage in order to use a single websocket connection. The main window listens to messages from server putting incoming data into a localStorage property. The child window use an angular $watch on this property to put incoming data into a grid. The use of different windows and a single connection is a requirement.

The problem is that the controller of the child window seems not to be able to watch the localStorage property until the browser development tool (F12) is not open.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Sorry if this question is stupid; but are both windows from the same origin ?

Comment: how you manage your storage ? are you using ngStorage ? or directly js storage

Comment: Could you share `$watch` function

Comment: @aorfevre: yes, the child window can be opened from a button inside the main window and point to the same origin. And yes, I'm using the ngStorage library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an angular project also using localstorage and localforage.js. This statement is really narrowing your problem to the development tools though, no?:

> "until the browser development tool (F12) is not open."

Make sure this box is unchecked.

[image]

Reload the page and try again.

Or you might try this solution: [Using localstorage checks in a different window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25369236/using-localstorage-checks-in-a-different-window) using [window.postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

Our QA team reports several bugs stemming from having two windows open with localstorage, so the data access has to be tightly synchronized. So the child window would send data to the parent which would handle localstorage.

Comment: Thank you, but the uncheck of "Disable check" didn't worked. I will explain better:
when I open the child window, the grid gets filled with the data inside the localStorage, but it cannot get the updates. Then, if I open the developer tool, it starts to get the updates. Then, if I lose the focus of the child window, it doesn't get the updates. If I reopen the developer tools it starts to work again.

Comment: is it possible you have the same bug as mentioned here?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42975984/6254070 Which browser are you using?